# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController crashes while being dismissed in Simulator only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I get this crash in the simulator only. On a real device it works and debugs fine. 
(Therefore it is not too critical but I am working on a presentation for which the simulator comes handy.)

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {


    [self displayPerson:person];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The crash is on:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

All I see is: `"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BTP, subcode=0x0)"`

There is no specific output in the debug window. Zoombies is enabled. I do ARC. I am using storyboard but I call the ABPersonPicker... programmatically using the following code:

```
-(void)showPeoplePickerController
{

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }

    return;
}
```

Remember that it is running well on the devices that I have (iPod Touch 4th gen, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S)

Comment: have you tried it debug the code by putting the breakpoint, at which line its crashing.

Comment: also it may be dependent on iOS, is device and simulator iOS versions same?

Comment: It is iOS 6.0 (10A403) on both, device and simulator. Yes, I did set a breakpoint there. The call stack tells me, that the error occurs within CFHash which is called from dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you don't keep a strong reference to the picker. Add a ivar to hold it, then when done in the delegate callback, use a dispatch asyn block on the main queue to nil the ivar out and release it. (Sorry no code entering this from an iPad)

EDIT: look in your showPeoplePickerController method - you create the picker and save it in an automatic which gets released when you exit the method. You want to keep a strong reference to the picker by using an ivar instead of the automatic.

Then you don't want to release the picker in a delegate callback - this often works but will bite you at unexpected times, so you want to release this type of object after the delegate callback is done. In fact I usually set the objects delegate property to nil first if I can then release it with 'picker = nil' . In a block 'picker' gets turned into 'self->picker'. You can also use performSelector:afterDelay:0 too I just prefer blocks.

EDIT2: So what I do in

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:
```

is just return NO. I wait until this message:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
```

to dismis it. I also have some other code that pops a an action sheet that confirms saving a selected address and also does a dismiss, but its old code and not sure how it works now. In any case hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit further? We are talking about the delegate method shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson. As for my understanding while it is called the picker is still valid. I do not even need a weak reference because a reference to the picker is passed through to the delegate. The picker is still alive and valid. It even depends on the return value whether it should continue or not. However I will try it of course but I'd rather understand it too.

Comment: I've answered this same question a dozen times here on SO it's always the lack of strong reference. While the object is retained elsewhere it gets released prematurely and often simulator behavior is different than real devices.

Comment: I'll look at my code within the hour and get back. I use this myself no problems using modal methods. In mean time add log messages to verify using either modal methods to both present and dismiss or the newer ones but not mixing them.

Comment: Well, as I am currently on iOS 6 devices and simulators only, the newer ones are always available and therefore used.

Comment: I'll try that tonight. Thanks so far.

Comment: Still no improvement. Keeping a strong reference is a good idea for other reasons. I want access to the Address Book even after the view is dismissed. But it does not help with this issue. Not dismissing the view in shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson is not helpful either. On the contrary. The ABPicker will not disappear until the user actively presses "cancel" which is not quite right. Working with blocks or performSelector may be more helpful. However, I doubt that this path will lead so solving this particular issue.

Comment: You can do this or I can. You create a demo project and add just this address thing. Test in Simulator, and on device. Its all working perfectly (since millions of people are doing this now). Once you believe that the framework is working, the problem will be in your code. As I said above, I only found the one dismiss on cancel, there is another but its after I pop an alert and frankly didn't want to have to trace my whole down. Returning 'no' from shouldContinue should cause it to stop, no? Did you try sending a dismiss in a block to the main queue?